# Give out suffixes (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I mean:
Input: suffixes ["Hello"]
Output: ['ello','llo','lo','o'] or something..
The beginning is:

```
> suffixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
> suffixes [] = []
```

I think it is a little bit like

```
> drop (n+1) (x:xs) = drop n xs
> drop _ xs = xs
```

But here I want to omit always the first element of the "surviving" list. How to start?
Maybe

```
> suffixes as = [as!!2:xs]
```

or similar?

Answer (score 5):

`tails` from `Data.List` will do what you want.

```
tails "hello"
--["hello", "ello", "llo", "lo", "o", ""]--
```

It seems like you don't want the first element so you can `drop 1`.

Comment: Thanks. And how to do the same but with prefixes?

Comment: `Data.List.inits`  `inits "Hello" --> ["", "H", "He", "Hel", "Hell", "Hello"]`

Answer (score 4):

`Data.List.tails` can be used to get the list of all suffixes of another list, and you can use `drop 1` to drop the first element of the output list:

```
import Data.List
suffixes = drop 1 . tails
```

If you want the prefixes you can use `Data.List.inits`. Note this returns prefixes in increasing order or length, while `tails` returns suffixes in decreasing length order.

Comment: Thanks. And how to do the same but with prefixes? (When the only element I want is the first)

Comment: @haskellnoob - You can use `Data.List.inits` to get the prefixes